# tablelayoutpanel within a tablelayoutpanel disposal

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose, tablelayoutpanel

I have a tableLayoutPanel called tlpMaster.  It has 4 columns and 8 rows.  in 3 of the columns and each row, it has another tableLayoutPanel.  so thats 3 inner ones.  Inside those I have checkboxes that I need to be able to dispose.  Here is what I got so far but it seems to be disposing the tableLayoutPanels and not the checkboxes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
    {
        //loop throught the table layout panels and dispose
        Control tlpTemp = tlpMaster.GetControlFromPosition(j, i);
        while (tlpTemp.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
           tlpTemp.Controls[0].Dispose();
        }
     }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++)
    {
       //loop throught the table layout panels and dispose
       Control tlpTemp = tlpMaster.GetControlFromPosition(j, i);
       foreach(Control ctrl in tlpTemp.Controls)
       {
           while (ctrl.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                ctrl.Controls[0].Dispose();
            }
        }
     }
}
```